# finding Jordan canonform of $A^3$ given the minimal polynomial of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I'm having trouble with the following question:
we were given the following minimal polynomial of a matrix $A\in \mathbb {C}^{4 \times 4}: X^4-2X^3+X^2$. Now we are asked to find the Jordan canonical form of $A$ as well as $A^3.$ The case for $A$ is pretty easy, but I can't see how to derive the case for $A^3$ from it.
edit:
the minimal polynomial can be split into: $X^2(X-1)^2$. From what we have learned the Jordan form will then be:
$\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$.
We can know that matrix $A$ can be written in the form $A=P^{-1}JP,$ with $J$ the Jordan form. Then $A^3=P^{-1}J^3P,$ with $J^3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&4&1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$ The minimal polynomial of $A^3$ will be: $(X-1)^2.$ Since $(A^3-I)^2=(P^{-1}J^3P-P^{-1}IP)^2=P^{-1}(J^3-I)^2P=0.$ From here on out I am not sure how to proceed. I think since $\dim(Ker(J^3-I))=3$ this means the invariant system is: $\{2,1,1\}.$ From which would follow that the Jordanform is: $\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
1&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$
But on the last part I am not so sure about my reasoning.

Comment: It is useful to explain what you have tried and what you understand, so for example it would be helpful to give your solution for the Jordan form of A.

Answer (score 1):

Four mistakes (the first one is benign):

- $J^3=\begin{pmatrix}
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&\color{red}3&1\\
  \end{pmatrix}$ (not $\begin{pmatrix}
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&0&0\\
  0&0&1&0\\
  0&0&4&1\\
  \end{pmatrix}$).
- $(J^3-I)^2=\begin{pmatrix}
  I_2&0\\0&0\\
  \end{pmatrix}\color{red}\ne0$;
- the minimal polynomial of $A^3$, i.e. of $J^3$, is not $(X-1)^2$ but $\color{red}X(X-1)^2$;
- $\dim\ker(J^3-I)=\color{red}1$, not $3$.

Now, directly (via a rescaling of the fourth basis vector), $J^3$ is similar to $\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
\end{pmatrix}$, which is therefore the Jordan form of $A^3$. Note that the Jordan form of $A^n$ is the same for every $n\ge2$.

Comment: okay, thanks a lot.